# Reshape wide data to long when variables have different naming pattern in R

Tags: r, statistics, reshape, data-cleaning, longitudinal

I have a wide data set with the following variable names (a simplified example see below).

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("00000001", "00000002", 
                                                      "00000003", "00000004"), class = "factor"), 
                     r1weight = c(56, 76, 87, 64), 
                     r2weight = c(57, 75, 88, 66), 
                     r3weight = c(56, 76, 87, 65), 
                     r4weight = c(56L, 73L, 85L, 63L), 
                     r5weight = c(55L, 77L, 84L, 65L), 
                     r1height = c(151L, 163L, 173L, 153L), 
                     r2height = c(154L, 164L, NA, 154L), 
                     r3height = c(NA, 165L, NA, 152L), 
                     r4height = c(153L, 162L, 172L, 154L), 
                     r5height = c(152,161,171,154), 
                     bmi2002  = c(27.0, 23.9,20.1,23.9),
                     bmi2004  = c(20.0, 29.9,21.1,27.3),
                     bmi2006  = c(21.0, 21.9,23.1,24.3),
                     bmi2008  = c(21.2, 21.2,23.4,24.5),
                     bmi2010  = c(24.1, 25.9, 26.2,28.3)),
                      class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> df
 id r1weight r2weight r3weight r4weight r5weight r1height r2height r3height r4height r5height bmi2002 bmi2004 bmi2006 bmi2008 bmi2010
1 00000001       56       57       56       56       55      151      154       NA      153      152    27.0    20.0    21.0    21.2    24.1
2 00000002       76       75       76       73       77      163      164      165      162      161    23.9    29.9    21.9    21.2    25.9
3 00000003       87       88       87       85       84      173       NA       NA      172      171    20.1    21.1    23.1    23.4    26.2
4 00000004       64       66       65       63       65      153      154      152      154      154    23.9    27.3    24.3    24.5    28.3
```

I want to convert the wide format data set to the long format data set. I have tried the reshape function, but I don't know how to use reshape function when the naming pattern of longitudinal variables is different. Also, reshape function requires me to specify each variable set, and it's a lot of work in my real analysis.

Is there any easier way for me to handle reshaping data from wide to long in my case?

For your reference, I have attached the name list of the real data that I need to handle:

```
[1] "hhid"              "rahhidpn.x"        "pn"                "reshhidpn.x"       "r1agey_e"          "r2agey_e"         
  [7] "r3agey_e"          "r4agey_e"          "r5agey_e"          "r6agey_e"          "r7agey_e"          "r8agey_e"         
 [13] "r9agey_e"          "r10agey_e"         "r11agey_e"         "r12agey_e"         "r13agey_e"         "r14agey_e"        
 [19] "respagey_e"        "r1mstat"           "r2mstat"           "r3mstat"           "r4mstat"           "r5mstat"          
 [25] "r6mstat"           "r7mstat"           "r8mstat"           "r9mstat"           "r10mstat"          "r11mstat"         
 [31] "r12mstat"          "r13mstat"          "r14mstat"          "remstat"           "rabyear"           "ragender"         
 [37] "rabplace"          "raedyrs"           "raedegrm"          "r1jcocc"           "r2jcocc"           "r3jcocc"          
 [43] "r4jcocc"           "r5jcocc"           "r6jcocc"           "r7jcocc"           "r8jcocc"           "r9jcocc"          
 [49] "r10jcocc"          "r11jcocc"          "r12jcocc"          "r13jcocc"          "r14jcocc"          "r7mdactx"         
 [55] "r8mdactx"          "r9mdactx"          "r10mdactx"         "r11mdactx"         "r12mdactx"         "r13mdactx"        
 [61] "r14mdactx"         "r7ltactx"          "r8ltactx"          "r9ltactx"          "r10ltactx"         "r11ltactx"        
 [67] "r12ltactx"         "r13ltactx"         "r14ltactx"         "r3drinkn"          "r4drinkn"          "r5drinkn"         
 [73] "r6drinkn"          "r7drinkn"          "r8drinkn"          "r9drinkn"          "r10drinkn"         "r11drinkn"        
 [79] "r12drinkn"         "r13drinkn"         "r14drinkn"         "r1smoken"          "r2smoken"          "r3smoken"         
 [85] "r4smoken"          "r5smoken"          "r6smoken"          "r7smoken"          "r8smoken"          "r9smoken"         
 [91] "r10smoken"         "r11smoken"         "r12smoken"         "r13smoken"         "r14smoken"         "r1bmi"            
 [97] "r2bmi"             "r3bmi"             "r4bmi"             "r5bmi"             "r6bmi"             "r7bmi"            
[103] "r8bmi"             "r9bmi"             "r10bmi"            "r11bmi"            "r12bmi"            "r13bmi"           
[109] "r14bmi"            "r8pmbmi"           "r9pmbmi"           "r10pmbmi"          "r11pmbmi"          "r12pmbmi"         
[115] "r13pmbmi"          "r14pmbmi"          "r2cesd"            "r3cesd"            "r4cesd"            "r5cesd"           
[121] "r6cesd"            "r7cesd"            "r8cesd"            "r9cesd"            "r10cesd"           "r11cesd"          
[127] "r12cesd"           "r13cesd"           "r14cesd"           "r1strok"           "r2strok"           "r3strok"          
[133] "r4strok"           "r5strok"           "r6strok"           "r7strok"           "r8strok"           "r9strok"          
[139] "r10strok"          "r11strok"          "r12strok"          "r13strok"          "r14strok"          "r1diab"           
[145] "r2diab"            "r3diab"            "r4diab"            "r5diab"            "r6diab"            "r7diab"           
[151] "r8diab"            "r9diab"            "r10diab"           "r11diab"           "r12diab"           "r13diab"          
[157] "r14diab"           "r1heart"           "r2heart"           "r3heart"           "r4heart"           "r5heart"          
[163] "r6heart"           "r7heart"           "r8heart"           "r9heart"           "r10heart"          "r11heart"         
[169] "r12heart"          "r13heart"          "r14heart"          "r1hibp"            "r2hibp"            "r3hibp"           
[175] "r4hibp"            "r5hibp"            "r6hibp"            "r7hibp"            "r8hibp"            "r9hibp"           
[181] "r10hibp"           "r11hibp"           "r12hibp"           "r13hibp"           "r14hibp"           "rahhidpn.y"       
[187] "reshhidpn.y"       "h1atotb"           "h2atotb"           "h3atotb"           "h4atotb"           "h5atotb"          
[193] "h6atotb"           "h7atotb"           "h8atotb"           "h9atotb"           "h10atotb"          "h11atotb"         
[199] "h12atotb"          "h13atotb"          "h14atotb"          "imrc_imp2018"      "imrc_imp2016"      "imrc_imp1995"     
[205] "imrc_imp1996"      "imrc_imp1998"      "imrc_imp2000"      "imrc_imp2002"      "imrc_imp2004"      "imrc_imp2006"     
[211] "imrc_imp2008"      "imrc_imp2010"      "imrc_imp2012"      "imrc_imp2014"      "dlrc_imp2018"      "dlrc_imp2016"     
[217] "dlrc_imp1995"      "dlrc_imp1996"      "dlrc_imp1998"      "dlrc_imp2000"      "dlrc_imp2002"      "dlrc_imp2004"     
[223] "dlrc_imp2006"      "dlrc_imp2008"      "dlrc_imp2010"      "dlrc_imp2012"      "dlrc_imp2014"      "ser7_imp2018"     
[229] "ser7_imp2016"      "ser7_imp1995"      "ser7_imp1996"      "ser7_imp1998"      "ser7_imp2000"      "ser7_imp2002"     
[235] "ser7_imp2004"      "ser7_imp2006"      "ser7_imp2008"      "ser7_imp2010"      "ser7_imp2012"      "ser7_imp2014"     
[241] "bwc20_imp2018"     "bwc20_imp2016"     "bwc20_imp1995"     "bwc20_imp1996"     "bwc20_imp1998"     "bwc20_imp2000"    
[247] "bwc20_imp2002"     "bwc20_imp2004"     "bwc20_imp2006"     "bwc20_imp2008"     "bwc20_imp2010"     "bwc20_imp2012"    
[253] "bwc20_imp2014"     "cogtot27_imp2018"  "cogtot27_imp2016"  "cogtot27_imp1995"  "cogtot27_imp1996"  "cogtot27_imp1998" 
[259] "cogtot27_imp2000"  "cogtot27_imp2002"  "cogtot27_imp2004"  "cogtot27_imp2006"  "cogtot27_imp2008"  "cogtot27_imp2010" 
[265] "cogtot27_imp2012"  "cogtot27_imp2014"  "cogfunction2018"   "cogfunction2016"   "cogfunction1995"   "cogfunction1996"  
[271] "cogfunction1998"   "cogfunction2000"   "cogfunction2002"   "cogfunction2004"   "cogfunction2006"   "cogfunction2008"  
[277] "cogfunction2010"   "cogfunction2012"   "cogfunction2014"   "proxy2018"         "proxy2016"         "proxy1995"        
[283] "proxy1996"         "proxy1998"         "proxy2000"         "proxy2002"         "proxy2004"         "proxy2006"        
[289] "proxy2008"         "proxy2010"         "proxy2012"         "proxy2014"         "PC1_5A"            "PC1_5B"           
[295] "PC1_5C"            "PC1_5D"            "PC1_5E"            "PC6_10A"           "PC6_10B"           "PC6_10C"          
[301] "PC6_10D"           "PC6_10E"           "E4_AD_IGAP13"      "E4_AD2_IGAP13"     "E4_GWAD2NA_IGAP19" "E4_GWAD2WA_IGAP19"
[307] "E4_01AD2NA_IGAP19" "E4_01AD2WA_IGAP19" "myrs"              "fyrs"              "humcap"            "famstr"           
[313] "maternal"          "soccap"            "ave_fin_re"        "fincap"            "cses_index"        "fin_inst"         
[319] "hhidpn"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reshape`, `pivot_longer`, and `pivot_wider` are variations of the same idea. For any of them, you need a column that's unique for the data. So let's say you wanted to change all of the data into a longer format, then add a column with the row numbers and made that your independent column. In pivots in this answer, I just left the first column as the static field and pivoted everything else.

For the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)
                              
df1 <- pivot_longer(df, cols = r1weight:bmi2010, # inclusively all columns between
                    names_to = "fields", values_to = "values")
head(df1)
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   id       fields   values
#   <fct>    <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 00000001 r1weight     56
# 2 00000001 r2weight     57
# 3 00000001 r3weight     56
# 4 00000001 r4weight     56
# 5 00000001 r5weight     55
# 6 00000001 r1height    151 

# frame is now 60 observations with three columns
```

I also created a data structure with all of the column names you provided. (`df4` is a vector of the column names you provided in your question.)

```
df5 <- matrix(ncol = length(df4), nrow = 100, dimnames = list(1:100, df4))
colnames(df5)[c(1, 2, 319)]  
# [1] "hhid"       "rahhidpn.x" "hhidpn"     

df5 <- as.data.frame(df5)

df6 <- pivot_longer(df5, cols = rahhidpn.x:hhidpn, # inclusively all columns between
                    names_to = "fields", values_to = "values")

nrow(df6)
# [1] 31800 

ncol(df6)
# [1] 3
```